# Am I using API in react correctly? I am not getting any output

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import "../Track.css";

const Tracker = () => {

    const[data,setData]= useState([]);

    const getCovidData = async() =>{
         const res =    await fetch('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest');
         const actualData = await  res.json();
         console.log(actualData.regional);
         setData(actualData.regional);

    }
   
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getCovidData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
         
         <div className="conatiner-fluid mt-5">
             <div className="main-heading">
              <h1 className="mb-5 text-center"> <span className="font-weight-bold">INDIA</span> COVID-19 DASHBOARD</h1>
             </div>
  
            <div className="table-responsive">
                <table className="table table-hover">
                    <thead className="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th> STATE</th>
                            <th> CONFIRMED</th>
                            <th> RECOVERED</th>
                            <th> DEATHS</th>
                            <th> ACTIVE</th>
                            <th> UPDATED</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody>

                        {
                             data && data.map((curElem,ind,regional) => {
                                return(
                                <tr key={ind}>
                                    <th> {curElem?.loc} </th>
                                    <td> {curElem?.confirmedCasesIndian} </td>
                                    <td> {curElem?.discharged} </td>
                                    <td> {curElem?.deaths} </td>
                                
                                    <td> {curElem?.lastOriginUpdate} </td>
                                </tr>
                                )
                            })
                        }    
                            
                    </tbody> 
                </table> 
            </div>

         </div>   
        </>
    )
}

export default Tracker
```

I am not getting output of api values in the output page. Pls help as their may be the mistake in map function. pls share your views and and share solution if possible.

Comment: Please add to the question output of `console.log(actualData.regional);`

Comment: The api returns an object of `{ ... , data: { ..., regional: { ... } } }`, so you should use `setData(actualData.data.regional)`

Comment: thanks man one more question lastOriginUpdate i want to add in project but it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

**regional** is inside **data** object.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
   "summary": {...}
   "unofficial-summary" : [...],
   "regional" : [...]
   ...
  }
}
```

You need to change `setData(actualData.regional);` as below

```
// ...
const getCovidData = async() =>{
         const res =    await fetch('https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest');
         const actualData = await  res.json();
         console.log(actualData.regional);
         setData(actualData.data.regional);
    
    }
```